# special characters in name field for search

Tags: html, forms

We are creating a quick find search field.

The html is like so:

```
<form>
                    <fieldset class="search">
                    <input class="contact-propid" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="enter property id">
                    <button class="btn" title="Search"></button>

                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

the expected search term is like : p-442749379

And the dest url looks like:

thissite.com/listing.php?id=p-442749379

Now this quick search is in the header of all pages..
And I see if I add : name="listing.php?id=" in the input class , it nearly gets me to where I want to go ...

Except the browser converts the ? and = and doesnt render these in the browser correctly

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/EdKpM/

oh and it puts a ? before listing

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="listing.php" method="GET">
     <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="enter property id">
     <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Set an `action` and `method` on the `<form>` and a `name` on the `<input>` element and it'll do what you want.